# what to use for data integrity check at application level for mongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, spring-data-mongodb, hibernate-ogm

I am migrating from RDBMS to mongoDb . i need to do data integrity checks for eg. adding constraint , enforcing schema validation, etc

i came around few blogs where they have mentioned to use spring data mongodb , mongoosejs , hibernate OGM etc. i am new at this can somebody suggest which one to use ?

Comment: Your question contains ORM/ODMs from multiple languages and backgrounds (hence the ORM and ODM) as such this question seems more like a software recs question with no clear goal.

Comment: sorry for the confusion.i need a framework in my application level which can help me in controlling the integrity checks .

Comment: We don't really do software recs on this site due to their opinionated nature, only you know what is "best" for your project.

Comment: @rahul: Its more of opinonated, quick articles which might help you.. http://www.slideshare.net/mongodb/migrating-from-rdbms-to-mongodb https://www.mongodb.com/collateral/rdbms-mongodb-migration-guide